# Visual studio only runs in Safe Mode

Tags: windows-10, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I was using visual studio, when all of a sudden it would no longer open. I click on the icon and nothing happens. I've rebooted and reinstalled it multiple times. I just found out it does however run fine in SafeMode. 
I ran the 'devEnv /Log' command and the log file contained near nothing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="ActivityLog.xsl"?>
<activity>
  <entry>
    <record>1</record>
    <time>2019/08/06 07:26:18.691</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 version: 16.0.29116.78</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>2</record>
    <time>2019/08/06 07:26:18.692</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Log ID</description>
    <guid>{F6B459C1-E9E6-404F-9923-01F39E683715}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>3</record>
    <time>2019/08/06 07:26:18.693</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Running in isolation mode.</description>
  </entry>
</activity>
```

Does anyone know what the issue could be?
Really appreciate any help, it sucks not being able to code!

Comment: When running in safe mode have you checked whether there are any extensions installed? If so, have you tried disabling them manually? It may also be worth removing any Visual Studio optional components that you don't actually need

Comment: I just tried it, sadly, no success.

Comment: Which Safe mode - that of Windows or `devenv.exe /SafeMode`?

Comment: Windows safe mode

Comment: Also I'm using visual studio 2019, just tried 2017 and the same problem

Comment: @Simkoo did you managed to resolve it? I am having the same issue after installing visual studio latest version as I looked at the logs it appears that I have the same issue you had.

Comment: I even tried to use WinDBG tools to investigate if there is another process terminating it like Antivirus or something else but found that the process terminate itself with the following message "The process exited with code -1"